# How to run the same python code for multiple input files

Tags: python, loops, input

I have two output files which contain the same data (but different values). I'm using the following Python code to read them and return the data/value that I want:

```
upper = input("Enter file name (upper): ")
lower = input("Enter file name (lower): ")

fhr = open(upper)
for line in fhr:
    word = line.rstrip().split()
    if len(word) > 1 and word[1] == '1:47':
        try:
            sabs = word[2]
        except:
            continue
        tot_upper = float(sabs)
        print('Total upper:', tot_upper)
fhr.close()

fhr = open(lower)
for line in fhr:
    word = line.rstrip().split()
    if len(word) > 1 and word[1] == '1:47':
        try:
            sabs = word[2]
        except:
            continue
        tot_lower = float(sabs)
        print('Total lower:', tot_lower)
fhr.close()
```

Which gives me the output:

```
Total upper: x
Total lower: y
```

Is there are way that I can simplify the code such that I open the first file, run the code, then loop back to the beginning, open the second file and run the same code? Something like this:

```
upper = input("Enter file name (upper): ")
lower = input("Enter file name (lower): ")

file = [upper, lower]

for inp in file:
    fhr = open(file)
    for line in fhr:
        word = line.rstrip().split()
        if len(word) > 1 and word[1] == '1:47':
            try:
                sabs = word[2]
            except:
                continue
            if inp == upper:
                tot_upper = float(sabs)
                print('Total upper:', tot_upper)
            elif inp == lower:
                tot_lower = float(sabs)
                print('Total lower:', tot_lower
    fhr.close()
```

I still want the same output:

```
Total upper: x
Total lower: y
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably need to use functions:

```
upper = input("Enter file name (upper): ")
lower = input("Enter file name (lower): ")

def f(name, s): # idk what is the function for so change to a custom name
    fhr = open(name)
    for line in fhr:
        word = line.rstrip().split()
        if len(word) > 1 and word[1] == '1:47':
            try:
                sabs = word[2]
            except:
                continue
            tot = float(sabs)
            print(f'Total {s}:', tot)
    fhr.close()

f(upper, 'upper')
f(lower, 'lower')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Is it possible for me to add or subtract the values from each other when the code is in this form? For example, diff = upper - lower

Comment: You might want to use `return` to return the value to the caller. If you're not familiar with functions (and their parameters and the `return` statement) please consult a Python tutorial of your choice.

Comment: I can't really answer because I don't understand what will the function return ? sum of all total values ?

Comment: The function is returning a single value e.g. upper = 850.5, lower = 800.5. I'll need to convert from str to float but could I do upper - lower = 50.0?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for label in 'upper', 'lower':
   # Ask for filename, using the label.
   # Process the file.
   # Print the result, using the label.
```